# unable to install Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql from nuget package

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework

I am creating a new project using entity framework and MySql using the below example.

[CSharp Point Example](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/tutorial-use-entity-framework-core-5-0-in-net-core-3-1-with-mysql-database-by2/)

now I had already installed,

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore (v5.0.0 – the latest stable version)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools (v5.0.0 – the latest stable version)
```

but when I tried installing the package `Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql (version 5.0.0-alpha.2)`

1. there is no specific alpha.2 package in the nuget package manager.

[image]

2. I am getting the error: NU1605: Detected package downgrade: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore from 5.0.5 to 5.0.0. Reference the package directly from the project to select a different version.

complete error below

> Restoring packages for
> D:\Ibrahim\EFCore\EFCoreMySql\EFCoreMySql\EFCoreMySql.csproj...
> NU1605: Detected package downgrade: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore from
> 5.0.5 to 5.0.0. Reference the package directly from the project to select a different version.   EFCoreMySql ->
> Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql 5.0.0 ->
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational 5.0.5 ->
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore (>= 5.0.5)   EFCoreMySql ->
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore (>= 5.0.0)

the first 2 nuget packages are shown below in the screenshot

[image]

when I tried the same with nuget console I get the following error

> dotnet : Could not find any project in
> `D:\Ibrahim\EFCore\EFCoreMySql\`. At line:1 char:1
>
> - dotnet add package Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql --version 5.0.0-a ...
> - ```
>     + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Could not find ...\EFCoreMySql\`.:String) [], RemoteException
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
>   ```

Comment: The tutorial you're following is very old and recommends out-of-support versions of Pomelo and .NET. I would suggest using the latest stable version of all packages instead. You can find a more up-to-date tutorial here: https://mysqlconnector.net/tutorials/efcore/